# Tkinter-Pandas.read_csv: Cambiar el archivo con el que estoy trabajando

Tags: python, tkinter

Mi aplicación al ser ejecutada hace aparecer un primer root, con 2 botones, uno para seleccionar un archivo, el otro para empezar a trabajar con el archivo en otro root. Estas son las funciones que uso:

```
primera_raiz=Tk()

def seleccion():
    global file
    archivo=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Seleccionar archivo txt",filetypes=(("Archivos txt","*.txt"),("Todos los archivos","*.*")))
    file=archivo

def ingreso():
    primera_raiz.destroy()

primera_raiz.mainloop()
```

Cómo veran, uso una variable global llamada file, que sirve como primer argumento de pd.read_csv. Escribo solo el código que viene al caso (esto ya pertenece al segundo root):

```
f= pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\t", header=None,parse_dates={"Fecha": [1, 2, 0]},index_col="Fecha")
f.columns=["Prec","Tmax","Tmin"]
pd.set_option("display.max_rows",None)
```

Dentro de este segundo root tengo un menú, una de las opciones es "Abrir", la idea es empezar a trabajar con un nuevo archivo si así el usuario lo quiere. Este es el command:

```
def abrir():
    global file
    archivo=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Seleccionar archivo txt",filetypes=(("Archivos txt","*.txt"),("Todos los archivos","*.*")))
    file=archivo
```

El problema es que esta última función no hace ningún cambio, el archivo con el que trabajo sigue siendo el mismo. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Aclaración: la función abrir() está escrita antes que el read.csv, obviamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo pude hacer por mi cuenta, escribiendo el código del read.csv dentro de la función seleccion() y sólo considerando como variable global a "f", de esta manera la función abrir() deja de tener sentido y me ahorro algo de código.

```
def seleccion():
    file=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Seleccionar archivo txt",filetypes=(("Archivos txt","*.txt"),("Todos los archivos","*.*")))
    global f
    f= pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\t", header=None,parse_dates={"Fecha": [1, 2, 0]},index_col="Fecha")
    f.columns=["Prec","Tmax","Tmin"]
    pd.set_option("display.max_rows",None)
```